# HTML5 with Flash fallback to display a Wowza stream

Tags: flash, html5-video, wowza

I'm trying to use VideoJS to display a video stream that would be readable on most recent platforms (desktop and mobile).

The video is hosted on a Wowza server and is available in multiple formats:

```
rtmp://176.9.93.207:1935/vod/mp4:inazimi.mp4
http://176.9.93.207:1935/vod/mp4:inazimi.mp4/playlist.m3u8
```

I couldn't make it work with [VideoJS](http://videojs.com/). I also tried with [MediaElement](http://mediaelementjs.com/) and [Projekktor](http://www.projekktor.com/) with no success. The only one that worked is [JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players) (tested with IE9, FF15, Chrome, iPad) with the following configuration, but I need an open source solution:

```
jwplayer("vid").setup({
    height: 276,
    width: 490,
    image: "video.jpg",
    modes: [
        {
            type: "html5",
            config: {
                file: "http://176.9.93.207:1935/vod/mp4:inazimi.mp4/playlist.m3u8"
            }
        },
        {
            type: "flash",
            src: "player.swf",
            config: {
                file: "mp4:inazimi.mp4",
                streamer: "rtmp://176.9.93.207:1935/vod",
                provider: "rtmp"
            }
        },
        { type: "download" }
    ]
});
```

It looks like the scripts are selecting the wrong protocol but I can't figure out how to configure it correctly. Has anyone had success with Wowza videos in HTML5/Flash players?